# Latent Profile Analysis in R

Tags: r

I would like to know if anyone does know a possibility to conduct a latent profile analysis within R. This kind of SEM-model utilizing continuous manifest variables to identify a latent categorial variable can be done within MPLUS (see [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mplus/dae/lca1.htm) for an example), but I did not find any comparable approaches within lavaan or any other R-package (although I am not sure if openMX can do it).

Questions:

1.) Does anyone has a suggestion for doing this as a SEM within R?

2.) Would be any classification algorithm like clustering or ordinal regression also appropriate to do the job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the mclustModel in the mclust library?

```
library(foreign)

library(mclust)

idd<- read.dta(data)

idd_ss <-subset(idd,select=c(variable1, variable2, variabel3, variable4, variable5))

iddBIC<- mclustBIC(idd_ss)

cl <- mclustModel(idd_ss,iddBIC)

cl
```

Comment: You made my day! "mclust" works like a charme and gives me an equivalent answer to mplus!

Comment: We have developed a package that provides an interface to MCLUST to perform Latent Profile Analysis, titled `tidyLPA`. Its contributions are to use the models most commonly used as part of Latent Profile Analysis through MCLUST and to make it easier to use profiles in subsequent analyses. It is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/jrosen48/tidyLPA) and if we submit it to CRAN then I will add a link here later.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can try is `poLCA` which is a package outputting polytomous (categorical) latent classes.

Comment: Thank you! I already had the polCA-package in mind, but I hoped for a solution to really replicate the MPLUS-analysis...seems that I have to hope for the best with polCA or find someone with a copy of MPLUS!